# What is securing an application platform called?

Tags: terminology

I'm searching for the right terminology for this element of cyber security.

If I want to secure something like a PaaS for other applications to use, how is this usually called? It's not application security, because we are talking about the platform, and it's also not quite something like infrastructure security, as I consider the basic infrastructure (hardware, network etc.) as secure and am just looking at the platform as a layer in between.

As a practical example:
Consider having an already secured data center (including hardware, networks...). On this data center, an OpenShift/Kubernetes container platform is set up, which we want to secure. Again, we are not looking at the microservice applications, that are using the platform.

I am struggling to find the correct terminology for this element of security, as "platform security" seems to talk more about securing hardware platforms like smartphones. Are there other, more appropriate, less misunderstood terms?

Comment: I think you are looking for the term "hardening". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardening_(computing) and https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hardening

Comment: _platform_ is also used to indicate the running system (not exactly OS), like to say Windows Platform, Linux Platform, this helps in choosing the proper software you want to use on them.

Comment: Some tech terms are overloaded, so this is not a real concern, as long as the term is used in the proper context.